# How to get variables from text in Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell, variables

I want to get variables from text, for example our text is: "*Barren Gates - Devil*", we want get two variables from this text. First variable should be everything **before** *-* mark, *(**not** including last space, it **shouldn't** finish with space.)* second variable should be everything after - mark. For example:

```
artist=Barren Gates
songname=Devil
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
text="Barren Gates - Devil"
artist=`echo "$text" | sed 's/ - .*//'`
songname=`echo "$text" | sed 's/.*- //'`
```

If you are using bash then you can use its built-in suffix and prefix removal:

```
artist=${text% - *}
songname=${text#* - }
```